# Преобразовать строковые значения типа (1,3 млн руб.) в числовой тип, а те которые не могут быть преобразованы в числа заменить на NaN

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, dataframe

Есть `df` c тысячами столбцов в формате `object`, которые необходимо отформатировать, прежде чем конвертировать в формат `float`. Проблема в том, что иногда попадаются не стандартные значения, которые можно обрезать с помощью `str.replace`, а такие редкие мусорные значения, означающие совсем иные вещи, нежели суть столбца.

Например:

```
r_data_executions_blocks_0_items_118_sum 
NaN                  10165
10 000 руб.              4
781 760 руб.             1
40 922 руб.              1
200 руб.                 1
201 844 руб.             1
177 579 руб.             1
34198/15/50006-ИП        1
415 руб.                 1
21148/18/86014-ИП        1
1,3 млн руб.             1
176 427 руб.             1
Name: r_data_executions_blocks_0_items_118_sum, dtype: int64
```

Видно, что суммы типа `10 000 руб.` можно очистить от сокращений валюты и порядка величин, убрать пробел между разрядами. Значения же типа `34198/15/50006-ИП` нужно целиком по паттерну `ИП` заменить на "NaN".

Код типа

```
for n in df_common_fin.columns:
    if 'sum' in n:
        df_common_fin[n] = np.where(df_common_fin[n].str.contains('ИП', regex=False), 'NaN', df_common_fin[n])

        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].str.contains('ИП', regex=False)
        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].str.replace('руб', '')
        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].str.replace('млн', '00000')
        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].str.replace('млрд', '00000000')
        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].str.replace('Исполнительный лист', "NaN")
        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].str.replace('Сумма неизвестна', "NaN")
        df_common_fin[n].fillna('NaN', inplace=True)
        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].str.replace('Нет', 'NaN')
        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].str.replace('.', '')
        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].str.replace(',', '')
        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].str.replace(' ', '') 
        df_common_fin[n] = df_common_fin[n].astype(np.float64)
```

Не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае я бы обрабатывал (заменой) только интересующие нас строки (с суммами) и в самом конце использовал:

```
df[col_name] = pd.to_numeric(df[col_name], errors='coerce')
```

`errors='coerce'` превратит все строки, которые невозможно было преобразовать в числовые значения, в `NaN`. Т.е. обо всем "мусоре" позаботиться функция `pd.to_numeric()`.

---

```
def clean_amount(col):
    to_repl = ["\s*", "\*", "руб\.?", ",", "млн\.?", "млрд\.?"]
    val =     ["",    "",   "",       ".", "*10**6", "*10**9"]
    col = col.replace(to_repl, val, regex=True)
    mask = pd.to_numeric(c.str.replace('*','',regex=False), errors='coerce').notna()
    col.loc[mask] = pd.eval(col.loc[mask])
    return pd.to_numeric(col, errors='coerce')
```

Пример работы:

```
In [327]: df
Out[327]:
                  col
0                 NaN
1         10 000 руб.
2        781 760 руб.
3         40 922 руб.
4            200 руб.
5        201 844 руб.
6        177 579 руб.
7   34198/15/50006-ИП
8            415 руб.
9   21148/18/86014-ИП
10       1,3 млн руб.
11       176 427 руб.

In [328]: df['col_clean'] = clean_amount(df['col'])

In [329]: df
Out[329]:
                  col  col_clean
0                 NaN        NaN
1         10 000 руб.    10000.0
2        781 760 руб.   781760.0
3         40 922 руб.    40922.0
4            200 руб.      200.0
5        201 844 руб.   201844.0
6        177 579 руб.   177579.0
7   34198/15/50006-ИП        NaN
8            415 руб.      415.0
9   21148/18/86014-ИП        NaN
10       1,3 млн руб.  1300000.0
11       176 427 руб.   176427.0
```

Comment: Возникает ошибка:

AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values, which use np.object_ dtype in pandas

при это часть признаков конвертируется, часть нет. Что нужно проверить?

Comment: Очень странная работа в jupiter notebook. Если перезапускать ячейку несколько раз она прожевывает objectы во float

Comment: @StepanSokol, дополнил ответ реализацией

Comment: Выглядит круто! Спасибо!

Comment: После ваших комментариев я попробовал реализовать то, что сам насоветовал в ответе - на практике реализация оказалось немного сложнее чем в теории (как это часто бывает - все дело в мелочах) ;-)

Comment: Но вот эта функция уже может быть просто врезана в общий код? Ну кроме import re?

Comment: Не кодил на Perl, вообще страшная аллергия на обработку текстов :-(

Comment: Не попробовав, не ответить на ваш вопрос... Если все случаи учтены, то можно использовать. PS это еще повезло, что Pandas умеет обрабатывать тексты пакетно (в векторизированном виде) :)

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85703/discussion-between-stepan-sokol-and-maxu).